# Constructing R-tree for continuous data?

Tags: rtree

I want to construct an R-tree to index land-use data.

How do we index continuous data using an R-tree?

Comment: Why have you chosen an R-tree? For which kind of queries do you want to use the R-tree?

Comment: Hello Mesa, I want to use the R-tree for range queries (probably at different spatial resolutions).